# How can I create an output as csv file in HP Exstream?

Tags: hp-exstream

Hi I am new to HP Exstream. Trying to create an output in csv instead of pdf. 
In the document could not find any indication. Please help

Answer (score 1):

HP Exstream is used to generate output in AFP, PDF, HTML, PCL, etc. It doesnt support generating CSV as a output/output queue.

But, under "Data file" of an "Application" a report file can be generated. This report file can be delimited file. You can add any delimiter you want.